# How to declare a map with variable generics?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

I have a `Map` whose keys are of generic type `Key<T>`, and values are of type `List<T>`. If the key is an instance of `Key<String>`, the value must be a `List<String>`, and the same rule applies to any other key-value pairs. I have tried the following but it does not compile:

```
Map<T, List<T>> map;
```

At present I have to declare it with "partial" generics:

```
Map<Object, List> map;
```

I know this is bad but I currently have no better choice. Is it possible to use generics in this situation?

**UPDATE**

Maybe I didn't express my problem clearly. I want a map that is able to:

```
map.put(new Key<String>(), new ArrayList<String>());
map.put(new Key<Integer>(), new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

And the following code should not compile:

```
map.put(new Key<String>(), new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

The key and value should always have the same generic type while the generic type can be any, and obviously extending a map does not meet my requirement.

Comment: space should not be the issue. It's likely the way it is used. OP need to show more code to fix.

Comment: Are you using keys of type `T`, or keys of type `Key<T>`?

Comment: With your actual scenario, you should use encapsulation to solve your problem as Nishant and Geoff states in their answers, just adapt it to your actual code.

Comment: Encapsulation does not work here because I have only one map. I don't want to declare `Test<String>`, `Test<Integer>`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing library that does precisely this but it is not too hard to implement yourself. I've done something similar a few times in the past. You cannot use the standard Map interface but you can use a hash map inside to implement your class. To start, it might look something like this:

```
public class KeyMap {
  public static class Key<T> { }

  private final HashMap<Object,List<?>> values = new HashMap<Object,List<?>>();

  public <T> void put(Key<T> k, List<T> v) {
    values.put(k, v);
  }

  public <T> List<T> get(Key<T> k) {
    return (List<T>)values.get(k);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyMap a = new KeyMap();
    a.put(new Key<String>(), new ArrayList<String>());
    a.get(new Key<Integer>());
  }
}
```

Comment: You are actually wrapping my `Map<T, List<T>> map` into another class. Seems that a simple map can't meet my requirement, so this may be the last choice. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is what you want:

```
public class Test<T> extends HashMap<T, List<T>>
{
}
```

If you don't want a HashMap as the super class then change it to whatever concrete class you want.

Comment: But how could I use only one `Test` instance to store my data?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Could you expand on your question again?

Comment: The key and its associated value should always have the same generic type, such as `Key<String> --> List<String>` and `Key<Integer> --> List<Integer>`. With your solution, if I declare a `Test<String>`, then I will not be able to put a `Key<Integer> --> List<Integer>` to it.

Comment: If that was the system you were trying to make, how would you get the correctly typed values from it?

Comment: I think can use a cast like `List<String> list = (List<String>) map.get(new Key<String>())`, but before this, I must first be able to declare such a map.